# make div change position when other div does

Tags: html, css, position

I am trying to understand `css` positioning. 
What I am trying to accomplish is : I want that when I set a `div` position , `div`'s after it, change position respect of the first `div` moved ,without overlapping them.
Let's make an example :

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box1">
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
    </div>
    <div class="box3">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap{
    position: absolute;
    background-color:yellow;
    width:500px;
    height:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.box1,.box2,.box3{
    position: relative;
    width:450px;
    height:150px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.box1{background-color:red; top: 100px;}
.box2{background-color:green;}
.box3{background-color:blue;}
```

Now , when I set , e.g `top:100px` on `box1` , it goes `100px` from the top, but `box2` and `box3` still remains there. I want that when i set `top` position on one of the `div` they "suffer" the change of the set position , and not overlap or get overlapped by other `div`s 
I tried, as you can see, with `position: relative` but It did not reach my goal.

Sorry if I explained it better , it's hard to me to explain it in English.

Comment: Do you mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/eux4C/ ?

Comment: uhm.. no I'm talking of css only , i do not want to animate, I want that my div change position automatically when i change other divs position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`top` property (as `left`, `right` and `bottom`) is used to positioning absolute elements only.
giving this property to the element probably gives it absolute behavior.
to position a relative element you should use `margin-top` instead.

**[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/keM4C/1/)** is a working fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Use margin-top instead of top. Top/Bottom/Left/Right changes the position from where it would normally be, and therefore it doesn't affect the rest. Margins will affect the rest too.

http://jsfiddle.net/eux4C/3/

```
.box1{background-color:red; margin-top: 100px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

The css `top` property can be used only on elements with position `absolute` (as talked in chat :-).

For a relative positioned element you should use `margin-top` property like:

```
.box1 {background-color:red; margin-top: 100px;}
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/eux4C/4/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you really want to preserve the standard box model, rather than ignoring it.

Don't set a position: relative, and use padding
-top or margin-top to add the extra space.